# Scala currying with 'byname' parameters and non-'byname' parameters

Tags: scala

I have (had) an assumption that appears to be wrong.  My 'main' language in the past has been C++ and in C++ I could do function parameter binding like this in pseudo:

```
// declaration
void f(int param1, int param2);

// usage
func<void, int> boundfunc = bind(f, 1, _1)
func(2) // equivalent to f(1, 2)
```

The interesting bit is that if I replace `1` in the definition of `boundfunc` with a function call, then that function call is invoked at the bind site, not the call to `func`.

So, when trying to solidify the concept of currying in my head, I compare it with binding in C++ and I *assume* (incorrectly) that currying with a non-'byname' parameter would equate to the same idea - called at the 'bind site'.  Of course, this isn't what's happening, and I'm curious as to why `f` and `g` below behave the same.  I'm obviously missing something...

```
import scala.util.Random

class X { println("Constructing"); val r = new Random }

def f(limit: Int)(x: X) = x.r.nextInt(limit)
def g(limit: Int)(x: => X) = x.r.nextInt(limit)

def r = f(100)(new X) // Doesn't print "Constructing"
def s = g(100)(new X) // Doesn't print "Constructing"

r // prints "Constructing"
r // prints "Constructing"

s // also prints "Constructing"
s // also prints "Constructing"
```

I expect the definition of `s` to do what it's doing (i.e. not call 'new X') but I did expect the definition of `r` to call it due to the fact that `f` has a basic definition of the `x` parameter (i.e. non-'byname').

Now, as I said, there's clearly some basic FP concept I'm missing, which I hope to rectify soon, but I'd also like to know if there's a way to get the equivalent of parameter binding so that `new X` isn't called repeatedly.

(Edit after answer from barjak)

Indeed, the problem stems from my misuse of `def` in the creation of `r` and `s` - I should be using `val`, which makes the call to `new X` happen at the 'bind site'.

The last surprising thing is that the 'byname' parameter in `g` is resolved only once, when we create `s`, as opposed to when we evaluate `s` explicitly.  (i.e. "Constructing" is only printed when we define `r` and `s` as opposed to when we define `r` and when we evaluate `s`).

Now, my assumption is that Scala's doing the properly defined thing and binding `x` to the result of the second parameter and thus it doesn't matter, in the context of `s` or `r` whether `x` is 'byname' or not.

I suppose, if I wanted to evaluate `x` repeatedly, I would need more than a 'byname' parameter, and would require an explicit function parameter instead, which would evaluate repeatedly when evaluating `s`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`r` is declared with the keyword `def`, which actually means "reevaluate the expression for each call". I think you want to use the `val` keyword, which will evaluate the expression only once for each instanciation of `X`.

```
val r = f(100)(new X)
val s = g(100)(new X)
```

Otherwise, I think your interpretation is right.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understood by name parameters there is no great difference between `f` and `g` in

```
def f(limit: Int)(x: X) = x.r.nextInt(limit)
def g(limit: Int)(x: => X) = x.r.nextInt(limit)
```

because of evaluating `x` in body definitions only once.

But if you had a loop or so inside definition `x` could be evaluated more than one ... and then in `f` a `new X` would be evaluated only one time (before method call) but in `g` a `new X` is evaluated as often as the loop runs.

```
/* using x in body twice (for demonstration only) */
def f(limit: Int)(x: X) = { x.r.nextInt(limit); x.r.nextInt(limit) }
def g(limit: Int)(x: => X) = { x.r.nextInt(limit); x.r.nextInt(limit) }
val r = f(100)(new X) /* prints "Constructing" only one time */
val s = g(100)(new X) /* prints "Constructing" twice */
r /* Doesn't print "Constructing" */
r /* Doesn't print "Constructing" */
s /* Doesn't print "Constructing" */
s /* Doesn't print "Constructing" */
```

And finnally to bring **currying** into play perhaps you would like to bind `new X` to `x` which you can do with a swap of parameter lists in function definition. Then you could do

```
def f(x: X)(limit: Int) = x.r.nextInt(limit)
val r = f(new X)_
val s = f(new X)_
r(100)
r(200)
s(100)
s(200)
```

where `r` and `s` are two different (independent) random streams constructed with currying `f` (no need of by name parameters).